# Create primary key with two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, composite-primary-key

I have two tables, `bank_data` and `sec_data`. Table `bank_data` has the columns `id`, `date`, `asset`, and `liability`. The `date` column is divided into quarters.

```
  id    | date     |  asset    | liability           
--------+----------+--------------------
 1      | 6/30/2001|    333860 | 308524
 1      | 3/31/2001|    336896 | 311865
 1      | 9/30/2001|    349343 | 308524
 1      |12/31/2002|    353863 | 322659
 2      | 6/30/2001|    451297 | 425156
 2      | 3/31/2001|    411421 | 391846
 2      | 9/30/2001|    430178 | 41356
 2      |12/31/2002|    481687 | 46589
 3      | 6/30/2001|    106506 | 104532
 3      | 3/31/2001|    104196 | 102983
 3      | 9/30/2001|    106383 | 104865
 3      |12/31/2002|    107654 | 105867
```

Table `sec_data` has columns of `id`, `date`, and `security`. I combined the two tables into a new table named `new_table` in R using this code:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "CREATE TABLE new_table
         AS (SELECT sec_data.id, 
         bank_data.date, 
         bank_data.asset, 
         bank_data.liability, 
         sec_data.security
         FROM bank_data,bank_sec
         WHERE (bank_data.id = sec_data.id) AND
         (bank_data.date = sec_data.date)")
```

I would like to set two primary keys (`id` and `date`) in this R code without using pgAdmin. I want to use something like `Constraint bankkey Primary Key (id, date)` but the `AS` and `SELECT` functions are throwing me off.

Comment: This isn't an R question, it's a SQL question. You should be able to do this with something like [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-altertable.html). (And btw, you should use `dbExecute` when your query does not return anything, as in your `create table` query.)

Comment: Who `sec_data`? You assign `bank_sec` and do not use `implicit join` and use composite `primary key` like `alter table new_table add primary key(id,date)`

Comment: A table can only have at most one **primary key** - you mean a single primary key consisting of two columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First your query is wrong.. You say table `sec_data` but you assign table `bank_sec` and i am rephrase your query

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
    SELECT 
       sec_data.id, 
       bank_data.date, 
       bank_data.asset, 
       bank_data.liability, 
       sec_data.security
    FROM bank_data
         INNER JOIN sec_data on bank_data.id = sec_data.id
                             and bank_data.date = sec_data.date
```

Avoid using `Implicit Join` and use `Explicit Join` instead.. And as stated by @ a_horse_with_no_name you can't define more than 1 primary key in 1 table. So what you do are `Composite Primary Key`

Define :

> is a combination of two or more columns in a table that can be used to
>   uniquely identify each row in the table

So you need to `Alter Function` because Your create statement base on other table..

```
ALTER TABLE new_table
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, date);
```

Comment: For others whose create statement is NOT based on other tables the Primary Key can be defined in the create as:
`PRIMARY KEY (id, date)`

Answer (score 3):

You may run these two separate statements ( `create table`  and `Insert into`  )

```
CREATE TABLE new_table ( 
       id int, date date, asset int, liability int, security int,
        CONSTRAINT bankkey PRIMARY KEY (id, date)
           ) ;


INSERT INTO new_table (id,date,asset,liability,security)
        SELECT s.id, 
           b.date, 
           b.asset, 
           b.liability, 
           s.security
         FROM bank_data b JOIN bank_sec s
         ON b.id = s.id AND b.date = s.date;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6fcaeb222c18f838853e1c8aca0e9e71)

Answer (score 0):

To create the primary key you desire, run the following SQL statement after your `CREATE TABLE ... AS` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE new_table
   ADD CONSTRAINT bankkey PRIMARY KEY (id, date);
```

That has the advantage that the primary key index won't slow down the data insertion.